# Is it possible to change the shape of the "images" in the legend of an igraph plot?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Using:

```
legend(x=0, y=-1.2, xjust = 0.5, ncol=2, 
       c("men", "women"), pch=21, col="black", 
       pt.bg=c("gray", "gray"), pt.cex=1.5)
```

I get this legend on an `igraph` plot:

[image]

However I need the shape of "men" to be a square. Is that possible? And if so then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the parameter `pch = 22` the legend will display squares instead of circles. For different symbols use `pch = c(21, 22)`. For more information on controlling the plotting character, type `?pch` in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Control the legend shapes as you would colors, text....

```
legend(x = 10, y = 100, xjust = 0.5, ncol = 2, c("men", "women"),
    pch = c(22, 21),
    col = "black", pt.bg = c("gray", "gray"), pt.cex = 1.5)
```

[image]